# spark dataframe convert a few flattened columns to one array of struct column

Tags: python, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I'd like to have some guidance what functions in spark dataframe together with scala/python code to achieve this transformation.

given a dataframe which has below columns

```
columnA, columnB, columnA1, ColumnB1, ColumnA2, ColumnB2 .... ColumnA10, ColumnB10
eg.
Fat Value, Fat Measure, Salt Value, Salt Measure, Iron Value, Iron Measure
10, mg, 2 mg etc etc
```

I'd like to convert it to a column which has type : array of struct.
eg.

```
type=Fat
amount=10
measure=mg

type = Salt
amount=2
measure=mg
```

Comment: i see this example has 'hand made' array of struct, but i could not get hints from it https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-dataframe-array-of-struct/

Comment: The stack function could be used here

Comment: the structure of your data is a bit unclear to me. do you have more than two rows? and if you do, is only the first row cateogories (like `"Fat Value", "Fat Measure", ...`) with the all rows in each category being numbers or units of measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your data is a bit problematic because it seems like your first row are the category names, while the remaining rows are the values for each category. I don't know how you're loading your data, but I would probably load the first row as a header if possible – however there is a workaround to set the first row of your data as the header. This will make it much easier to construct your `F.struct` objects because you can pass the columns as string literals instead of the first row.

Here is a sample pyspark dataframe similar to yours:

```
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
|  columnA|    columnB|  columnA1|    columnB1|  columnA2|    columnB2|
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
|Fat Value|Fat Measure|Salt Value|Salt Measure|Iron Value|Iron Measure|
|       10|         mg|         2|          mg|         1|          mg|
|       20|         mg|        22|          mg|        12|          mg|
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
```

And here is the modified one:

```
new_schema = [x for x in df.collect()[0]]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df.tail(df.count()-1), new_schema)

+---------+-----------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
|Fat Value|Fat Measure|Salt Value|Salt Measure|Iron Value|Iron Measure|
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
|       10|         mg|         2|          mg|         1|          mg|
|       20|         mg|        22|          mg|        12|          mg|
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
```

We can create column groups from each consecutive pair of columns `[["Fat Value","Fat Measure],["Salt Value","Salt Measure"], ...]` assuming that the desired information comes in pairs of columns. Then we can create the struct using the information in the columns as well as the column names.

```
col_groups = [[df2.columns[2*i], df2.columns[2*i+1]] for i in range(int(len(df2.columns)/2))]
# [['Fat Value', 'Fat Measure'],
#  ['Salt Value', 'Salt Measure'],
#  ['Iron Value', 'Iron Measure']]

df3 = df2.select(
    [
        F.struct(
            F.col(cols[0]).alias(f"Value"), 
            F.col(cols[1]).alias(f"Measure"),
            F.lit(cols[0].split(" ")[0]).alias(f"Type"),
        ).alias(cols[0].split(" ")[0] + " info")
        for i,cols in enumerate(col_groups)
    ]
)

+-------------+--------------+--------------+
|     Fat info|     Salt info|     Iron info|
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
|{10, mg, Fat}| {2, mg, Salt}| {1, mg, Iron}|
|{20, mg, Fat}|{22, mg, Salt}|{12, mg, Iron}|
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
```

And below is the `schema` of `df3`:

```
root
 |-- Fat info: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- Value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Measure: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Type: string (nullable = false)
 |-- Salt info: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- Value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Measure: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Type: string (nullable = false)
 |-- Iron info: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- Value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Measure: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Type: string (nullable = false)
```

Comment: Hi @derek, thank you very much for getting back this to me. my question was a bit misleading, i actually have good header, but in the beginning i started with abstract way of asking the question: columnA, columnB etc, later i made it to be the real example i have.

Comment: it seems clear to me and should work, I will check and modify to make the 'Type' to be the 'field name' somehow (eg. Fat, Salt etc)

Comment: @soMuchToLearnAndShare i'm glad to hear my answer was helpful!

Comment: i think above answer does not return 'array' of struct; which is what i was after.

Comment: which is fine, the stack overflow shows array function can put a few columns into array :)